# meaning of go back through

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

I don't know the meaning of "go back through" in this sentence:
"You may have to **go back through** and "touch up" your design"
I've look up it in some dictionaries but finally i couldn't find its meaning. Help me

Comment: *through* = "all the way" ("from start to finish")

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it means you have to check again and make some little changes to improve your design,"go back through"means check again , re-check, look again